# Reading in doubles gives back zeros instead of actual values

Tags: java, eclipse, double

I am trying to read in a text file with accountnumbers and balances. I am reading in the accountnumbers as a string and the balances as a double, but I get all zeros for the balances instead of the actual values.

Here's what the file looks like:

```
0015      112.34
0020     4000.00
0034     9345.89
0069      723.50
0085     1500.00
0091     8237.31
0128       29.75
0129     -483.14
0135     2908.83
0189    10045.90
0251     5700.10
```

The second column are the balances.

My code, with the extra class to store the accounts with balances is the following

```
package Bank;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import ui.UIAuxiliaryMethods;

class Bank {

    PrintStream out;

     Bank() { 
            out = new PrintStream(System.out); 
            }

     void readFileIn() {
         Scanner fileScanner = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
         while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
             String Account = fileScanner.nextLine();
             readLine(Account);
         }
     }

     void readLine(String Account) {
         String[] part1 = Account.split(" ");
         String account = part1[0];
         String balance1 = part1[1];
         Scanner Balance = new Scanner(balance1);
         double balance = 0;
         double count1 = 0;
         while(Balance.hasNext()) {
             balance += Balance.nextDouble();
             count1++;
         }
             Accounts line = new Accounts(account, balance);
             out.printf("%s %.2f \n",line.account, line.balance);
         }

     void start() {
            readFileIn();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Bank().start();
    }

}

package Bank;

class Accounts {

    String account;
    double balance;

    Accounts(String account, double balance){

        this.account = account;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

}
```

The result I get is the following:

```
0015 0,00 
0020 0,00 
0034 0,00 
0069 0,00 
0085 0,00 
0091 0,00 
0128 0,00 
0129 0,00 
0135 0,00 
0189 0,00
```

Is there any way to fix this so that I get the actual balances?

Comment: why are you calling `Scanner Balance = new Scanner(balance1);` on balance one?

Comment: That's how I usually read things like this in. There are more efficient ways I think, but I am not that good with this.

Comment: while(Balance.hasNext()) {
             balance += Balance.nextDouble();
             count1++;
         } is not required

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an additional `Scanner` you can simply use `Double.parseDouble()` to get the value of the second column i.e.

```
void readLine(String Account) {
    String[] part1 = Account.split(" ");
    String account = part1[0];
    double balance = Double.parseDouble(part1[1]);
    Accounts line = new Accounts(account, balance);

    ...
}
```

If the columns are not split by a single space it is also better to use a more general separator like `split("\\s+")` which will accept multiple spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split(" +")` or better `split("\\s+")` for splitting on whitespace (tab also), multiple times, at least one. Also `hasNextLine/hasNextDouble` is better than `hasNext`.

In fact:

```
     String[] part1 = Account.split("\\s+");
     String account = part1[0];
     String balance1 = part1[1];
     double balance = Double.parseDouble(balance1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several spaces between the values. For example `"0015      112.34".split(" ")` becomes `{"0015","","","","","","","112.34"}` and when you use the index 1, you only get an empty string. You should split the line by the whole sequence of whitespace, like `account.split("\\s+")` (using a regular expression).

Also note that you don't need a Scanner to find the double value. You can just use `Double.valueOf(balanceAsString)`. And remember that by convention, all variable names should start with a lowercase letter.